# DB2 Milliseconds between two dates

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have two dates with datatype timestamp(10). Now I want to calculate the milliseconds between these two dates.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(1,CHAR(endtime- starttime))) AS "ms"
FROM TABLE
```

I got current error:

```
[Code: -183, SQL State: 22008]  A datetime arithmetic operation or a datetime scalar function has a result that is not within the va`lid range of dates.. SQLCODE=-183, SQLSTATE=22008, DRIVER=4.28.11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more accurate TIMESTAMPDIFF alternative.

```
SELECT 
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(1, CHAR (endtime - starttime)) / 1000
    AS TSDIFF_ORIG
, (DAYS             (endtime) - DAYS             (starttime)) * BIGINT (86400000)
+ (MIDNIGHT_SECONDS (endtime) - MIDNIGHT_SECONDS (starttime)) * 1000
+ (MICROSECOND      (endtime) - MICROSECOND      (starttime)) / 1000
    AS TSDIFF_REAL
FROM (VALUES (CURRENT TIMESTAMP, CURRENT TIMESTAMP + 35 MINUTE + 1.001 SECOND)) T (starttime, endtime)
```

| TSDIFF_ORIG | TSDIFF_REAL |
| --- | --- |
| 2101001 | 2101001 |

Answer (score 0):

TIMESTAMPDIFF returns an INTEGER, so the maximum value it can return is 2 147 483 647

So as the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-timestampdiff) tells

> Microseconds (the absolute value of the duration must be less than
> 3547.483648)

The maximum duration between the to timestamps when TIMESTAMPDIFF must return a number of microseconds is 35 minutes 47 seconds 483647 microseconds

Answer (score 0):

What is the timestamp difference between start and end? [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-timestampdiff) has a rather restrictive range. FWIW, 1 is microseconds and the maximum interval seems to be round 35 minutes:

```
db2 "with t(starttime,endtime) as (values (current_timestamp, current_timestamp + 35 minute)) select TIMESTAMPDIFF(1,CHAR(endtime - starttime)) from t" 

1          
-----------
 2100000000

  1 record(s) selected.

db2 "with t(starttime,endtime) as (values (current_timestamp, current_timestamp + 36 minute)) select TIMESTAMPDIFF(1,CHAR(endtime - starttime)) from t" 

1          
-----------
SQL0183N  A datetime arithmetic operation or a datetime scalar function has a 
result that is not within the valid range of dates.  SQLSTATE=22008
```

Also, beware that TIMESTAMPDIFF does some assumptions about the number of days in a month etc

The classic aproach to the problem is to convert your timestamps to the number of milliseconds since some start time (say epoch) and then subtract them.

A function like this (not thouroughly tested) may help:

```
create or replace function ms_since_epoch(ts timestamp)
returns bigint
    return extract(epoch from ts)*1000
         - extract(seconds from ts)::int
         + 1000*extract(milliseconds from ts) @
```